# upgrading problem black screen

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I am new to ubuntu I now have ubuntu 12.04 and I want to upgrade them to 12.10 and then to 13.04. So I follow some steps I installed 12.10 but when I reboot it I couldn't login and all I get was a black screen and nothing else. I pressed alt+ctr+f1 I logged in and I could use the terminal. So I reinstall 12.04 from usb and I need to know what to do to upgrade them successfully...

From a quick search I think that this is a problem from graphics card.
I have ATI Radeon hd 5500
and also when I opened them I could see the purple screen and then it turned black and I couldn't do anything.
Sorry for my really bad english too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can install directly the 13.04 version, only dont format the Home partition (if you have it isolated)

if not when you obtain console access try with:

```
startx
```

that will launch the graphical interface